# Edge coloring strategy

Tags: graph-theory

I found the best edge coloring for the next two graphs.

But is there some strategy for it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edge coloring is NP-Hard. The greedy algorithm is usually a good place to start. I am not familiar with any approximation algorithms off the top of my head, but that is also another good avenue to pursue.

Comment: @ml0105 What do you mean with edge coloring is an NP-hard problem? Is Vertex coloring also NP-hard?

Comment: Yes. Unless P=NP, I wouldn’t expect an easy solution to exist in general.

Answer (score 3):

The main observation is that the edge-chromatic number will be at least the maximum degree, i.e., $\chi'(G) \geq \Delta(G)$, simply because each edge incident with a maximum-degree vertex must have different colors.  In fact, [Vizing's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing%27s_theorem) goes further and says $$\chi'(G) \in \{\Delta(G),\Delta(G)+1\}.$$

The first graph achieves $\chi'(G)=\Delta(G)$ (meaning it's class one), as you demonstrate.  There's theoretical results which imply this, e.g., the Wikipedia page for Vizing's Theorem states "Vizing (1965) showed that a planar graph is of class one if its maximum degree is at least eight."

The second graph (the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph)) is not class one.

There's not going to be an efficient algorithm for this in general, since there's various NP-completeness results, e.g. Leven and Galil, [NP completeness of finding the chromatic index of regular graphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/0196-6774(83)90032-9), 1983.

- In the given examples, the most difficult task is proving $\chi'(G) \neq \Delta(G)$ in the Petersen graph, since it requires effort to check it can't be $3$-edge-colored.
- A greedy-like algorithm would likely work in practice to give a $\chi'(G)$-edge coloring; generally, when there's one coloring, there's zillions of others.